# Trigger after initialize in a model after default scope applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model which has a default scope

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :id, :name
  default_scope includes(:relation)

  after_initialize :do_something_with_relation

  def do_something_with_relation
    self.name += self.relation.name
  end
end
```

What I am trying to do here is appending the name of the relation to SomeModel object. I have added a default scope to support eager loading. But for some reason the relation is fetched for every object fetched using a where clause inspite of the eager loading.

```
SomeModel.where("name LIKE '%some name%'").all


SomeModel Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `some_models`.* FROM `some_models`
SomeRelation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `some_relations`.* FROM `some_relations` WHERE `some_relations`.`id` = some_id LIMIT 1
SomeRelation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `some_relations`.* FROM `some_relations` WHERE `some_relations`.`id` = some_id LIMIT 1
SomeRelation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `some_relations`.* FROM `some_relations` WHERE `some_relations`.`id` = some_id LIMIT 1
SomeRelation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `some_relations`.* FROM `some_relations` WHERE `some_relations`.`id` = some_id LIMIT 1
```

Is this a priority issue? That the eager loading takes place after the initialization of the object? If so is there a way to trigger the after initialize callback after the eager loading is done?

The result I was expecting was

```
SomeModel Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `some_models`.* FROM `some_models`
SomeRelation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `some_relations`.* FROM `some_relations` WHERE `some_relations`.`id` IN (some_id, some_other_id, ...)
```

I am using Rails 3.2

Comment: did you `reload!` (or restarted) your console to make Ruby aware of the changes in the files?

Comment: I did a reload! several times and then eventually even restarted my console. Tried to debug using pry as well.

Answer (score 1):

`after_initialize` is called before preloaded associations are set, so you will just have to call your custom method manually, after everything is fetched